# ESO Crown Riding Lessons, per character or per mount?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The riding lessons you can purchase in the Crown Store in Elder Scrolls Online, are these activated per character, or per mount, or per account?

I'm speaking of these lessons:

- Crown Lesson: Carry Capacity (10)
- Crown Lesson: Speed (10)
- Crown Lesson: Stamina (10)

All of these impact the mount, but since mounts are now in an account-wide collection, do these lessons apply to the mount, or only for the character I purchase them on?

Comment: Are these boosts temporary, or are they permenant for your character once you use them?

Comment: They are permanent for your character. Each of them can go up to 60. The carry capacity translates into bigger inventory for your character, the other two only applies while riding.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for that information!

Answer (score 3):

The lessons only apply to the character you use the lessons on, and persist even if that character changes to a different mount. Other characters will not get the increased bag space.

Comment: Does it count towards the max 120 capacity?  Or is it in addition to it?

Comment: good question, don't know yet.

Comment: Inventory space provided by mounts is in addition to inventory space purchased (bag vendor or Crown Store).